# gulp variable Variable names

Tags: javascript, gulp

I need to select a group of files in various locations that all end similarly with `gulp`, my project has the following lay out

> Areas
>   - Booking
>   --Emails
>   ---BookingEmail_Html_v1.cshtml
>   ---BookingEmail_Text_v1.cshtml
>   - Allerts
>   --Emails
>   ---AlertEmail_Html_v2.cshtml
>   ---AlertEmail_Text_v3.cshtml

and i need to select only the *Html* files from both email sub directories, i have tried the following but as i guessed it did not work.

```
return del('Areas/*/Emails/*_html_v*.cshtml');
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: How would that help with the file names? and would i not have to then add to the array every time i added a new sub folder to areas with emails in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
return del('Areas/**/Emails/*_Html_v*.cshtlm');
```

and make sure your task is in the same folder as `Areas` since you are calling it directly, else specify the right path to `Areas`.

You would notice the `**` and that's for matching any folder.